# app = web.Application(loop=loop) in aiohttp docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have a problem with `loop=loop` when I was reading the aiohttp docs. Is it a special and indispensable code? Or just a redundant reassignment that  `app = web.Application(loop)` works as well.

Server example:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

@asyncio.coroutine
def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(body=text.encode('utf-8'))


@asyncio.coroutine
def init(loop):
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)  #Why use loop=loop?
    app.router.add_route('GET', '/{name}', handle)

    srv = yield from loop.create_server(app.make_handler(),
                                        '127.0.0.1', 8080)
    print("Server started at http://127.0.0.1:8080")
    return srv

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(init(loop))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: For what its worth, and if I recall correctly from the source code, if you don't pass in the loop parameter, then I *think* it fetches and associates the loop internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loop` parameter from `web.Application` constructor is *keyword-only*
(see [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) for details).
So you should use `name=value` notation for it.